# Внешнее объединение Oracle и ANSI

Tags: sql, oracle, join, ansi

Добрый день. Есть псевдотаблицы

```
with t1 as (
   select 1 id from dual union all 
   select 2 id from dual union all 
   select 3 id from dual),
t2 as (
  select 2 id from dual union all 
  select 4 id from dual union all 
  select 5 id from dual),
t3 as (
  select 2 id from dual union all 
  select 3 id from dual union all 
  select 4 id from dual)
```

Если запустить следующий запрос:

```
select * 
from   t2, t3, t1
where  t2.id = t3.id
and    t1.id = t2.id(+)
```

то выдаст:

```
 |id|id|id|
 |--|--|--|
 |2 |2 | 2|
```

т.е. фактически сначала выполняется внешнее объединение, а затем внутреннее? Или вообще только внутренние?
По плану запроса нет вообще внешнего объединения. И всегда ли так?

Если запускаю следующие запросы с использованием синтаксиса ANSI:

```
select *
from   t2 
join   t3 on t2.id = t3.id
right  join t1 
on     t1.id = t2.id
```

и

```
select t2.id, 
       t3.id, 
       t1.id
from   t1
left   join t2 
on     t1.id = t2.id
left   join t3 
on     t2.id = t3.id
```

то все правильно и логично выводится.

```
 |id|id|id|
 |--|--|--|
 |2 |2 | 2|
 |  |  | 3|
 |  |  | 1|
```

С использованием синтаксиса Oracle такого результата можно добиться запросом:

```
select * 
from   ( select t3.id id, 
                t2.id id_
         from   t2, t3
         where  t2.id = t3.id
       ) t4, t1
where  t1.id = t4.id(+)
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, что именно делает оптимизатор? Правильно ли я понимаю, что 2 и 3 запросы он интерпретирует как 4-ый? И почему такой результат у первого запроса?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К сожалению Oracle применяет операцию left/right join только когда у *всех* упоминаний колонок необязательной таблицы стоит `(+)`. Даже такие примеры дадут разные результаты:

```
select *
  from t1, t2
 where t1.id=t2.id(+) and t2.X=5
-- Будет воспринято как обычный JOIN, т.к. t1.X=5 рассматривается после объединения

select *
  from t1, t2
 where t1.id=t2.id(+) and t2.X(+)=5
-- Тут (+) у обоих условий таблицы - они все считаются как записанные в фразе ON RIGHT/LEFT
```

Если вы не указали `(+)` хотя бы у одной колонки таблицы, участвующей в условиях, Oracle полностью игнорирует плюсы у остальных колонок.

И к большому сожалению при попытке написать `where t2.id(+) = t3.id
and t1.id = t2.id(+)`, что указало бы необязательность записей таблицы t2 по отношению к обоим другим таблицам, Oracle выдаст ошибку ORA-01417 и единственный путь этого избежать - вынести две основные таблицы в подзапрос, как вы и сделали в последнем примере.

Comment: Разве можно говорить про корректность? Оракл выполнил ровно то, что написано в запросе. Просто тот кто писал запрос, сам не понял, что написал

Comment: @lDrakonl Убрал слово "корректно", так наверно корректней смотрится :)

Answer (score 2):

Дело не в оптимизаторе, а в том, как именно Вы составили запрос.
В первом запросе условие соединения обрабатывается в `Where`.
Таким образом первый запрос можно переписать в таком виде:

```
select * 
from   t2 
inner  join t3 
on     t2.id = t3.id
right  join t1 
on     t1.id = t2.id
where  t2.id = t1.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Фактически в первом запросе указывается условие t1.id = t2.id = t3.id (ведь ты используешь AND), поэтому он одну строчку и выдает, так что все правильно делается.
При таком синтаксисе ты перемножаешь таблицы друг на друга, а не джойнишь. Это как бы аналог CROSS JOIN'a